How to show $\{y^*\otimes x: y^*\in S_{Y^*}, x\in S_X\}$ is rounded?
Let $X, Y$ be complex normed spaces. Let $X^*$ denotes the topological dual of $X$ and $S_X=\{x\in X:\|x\|=1\}$. Consider $A\subset X$. $A$ is called $\textbf{rounded}$ if $\mathbb{T} A=A$, where $\mathbb{T}=\{\lambda\in \mathbb{C}:|\lambda|=1\}$ and $\mathbb{T} A=\{\lambda a: \lambda\in \mathbb{T}, a\in A\}$.
$\textbf{Question:}$ How to show $\{y^*\otimes x: y^*\in S_{Y^*}, x\in S_X\}$ is rounded? Here $\otimes$ denotes the tensor product.
$\textbf{My attempt:}$ Let $A=\{y^*\otimes x: y^*\in S_{Y^*}, x\in S_X\}$. Let $\lambda\in \mathbb{T}$ and $y^*\otimes x\in A$. Now, we can represent $y^*\otimes x$ by the order pair $(y^*, x)$. Therefore, $\lambda [y^*\otimes x]=(\lambda y^*, \lambda x)$. But since $|\lambda|=1$ thus, $(\lambda y^*, \lambda x)\in S_{Y^*}\times S_X$. It follows that $\lambda [y^*\otimes x]\in A$ and consequently, $\mathbb{T} A\subseteq A$. It is straightforward that $A\subseteq \mathbb{T} A$. Thus, $\mathbb{T}A=A$ and consequently, $\{y^*\otimes x: y^*\in S_{Y^*}, x\in S_X\}$ is rounded.
$\textbf{My Confusion:}$ I do not have knowledge about tensor product. Can we write the tensor product as the above order pair i.e., $\lambda [y^*\otimes x]=(\lambda y^*, \lambda x)$ ? Is the above proof rightfully attempted? Please help me. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

A tensor product is a bilinear map, which means that you'll instead have
$$\lambda [y^*\otimes x]=(\lambda y^*)\otimes x = y^*\otimes (\lambda x)$$
but this means that you only have to adjust your proof slightly.

Thank you very much for your answer. Can you suggest a good text/book on Tensor product theory from a beginner's perspective of Banach space theory?

@Tuh I don't think I'll be able to help on that matter. I've only used tensor products here and there myself. You might have more luck making a question about this with the tag reference-request maybe? Check beforehand if you can find an existing post about it.

Sure. Thank you once again.
